# function calling error in ajax

Tags: jquery

```
function manageVoting() {
    $("div.votemaincontainer").each(function () {
        // variable Declaration and intialization.
        var myRating = parseInt($(this).find('#[id$=hfMyVote]').val());
        var currentVote = parseInt($(this).find('#[id$=hfCurrentVote]').val());
        $('.VoteDownImage').live(click, function () {
            ajaxcall(0);
        });
        $('.voteupImage').live(click, function () {
            ajaxcall(1);
        });
    }

    function ajaxcall(a){ // here it's giving error.
        var questionID = parseInt($(this).find('#[id$=currentquestionId]').val());
        var objectType = 100;
        var previousvote = 2;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'UserControls/Vote/VoteAction.aspx/Voting',
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: '{ObjectType: "' + objectType + '", guid: "' + currentGuid + '",previousVote: "' + previousvote + '",vote:"' + a + '"}',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var result = eval(data.d);
            }
        });
    }
    $(function () {
        //    manageVoting();
    });
```

Comment: Nishant - I improved the code indentation in your question using [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org). Proper code indentation can clear up problems quickly. :o) See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** After improving the code indentation in your question, it appears as though you forgot to close the `.each()` loop with `});` before the closing bracket for the `manageVoting()` function.

*Proper code indentation is extremely helpful.*

Also, it doesn't make too much sense to apply `.live()` in a loop. You only need to do that once.

Here's your code with the improvements:

```
  // Call these once on page load.
  // Note the difference in capitalization in your selectors. Make sure it is
  //    the same in your HTML classes
$('.VoteDownImage').live(click, function () {
    ajaxcall(0);
});
$('.voteupImage').live(click, function () {
    ajaxcall(1);
});

function manageVoting() {
    $("div.votemaincontainer").each(function () {
        // variable Declaration and intialization.
        var myRating = parseInt($(this).find('#[id$=hfMyVote]').val());
        var currentVote = parseInt($(this).find('#[id$=hfCurrentVote]').val());
    });  // closed the .each() loop
}

function ajaxcall(a){ // here it's giving error.
    var questionID = parseInt($(this).find('#[id$=currentquestionId]').val());
    var objectType = 100;
    var previousvote = 2;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'UserControls/Vote/VoteAction.aspx/Voting',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: '{ObjectType: "' + objectType + '", guid: "' + currentGuid + '",previousVote: "' + previousvote + '",vote:"' + a + '"}',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var result = eval(data.d);
        }
    });
}
$(function () {
    //    manageVoting();
});
```

---

**Original answer:**

You don't specify a type for function parameters (or any other variables) in javascript. This is because of loose typing, where any variable can be used to store any type.

This line:

```
function ajaxcall(int a)
```

should be:

```
function ajaxcall(a)
```

Comment: @Nishant - Can you provide more information? What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

@Nishant - when you get done unwinding your code there are a lot of problems.

From looking at your code you are trying to have up/down voting on images.

Well I have some questions and statements:

1. What are the local variable in `manageVoting` used for?
2. Why do you have variables starting with uppercase and some with lowercase?
3. The `this` reference in `parseInt($(this).find('#[id$=currentquestionId]').val())` is not what you are looking for in getting the id.
4. Try renaming your function to something other than `ajaxCall`.
5. Don't build your own query string let JavaScritp and jQuery handle that.

Here is a start with your code:

```
function updateVote(elementClicking, vote){ // here it's giving error.
     var imagVote = {
         ObjectType: 100,
         guid: parseInt($(elementClicking).find('#[id$=currentquestionId]').val()),
         previousVote: 2,
         vote: vote
     } ;

     $.ajax({
         url: 'UserControls/Vote/VoteAction.aspx/Voting',
         cache: false,
         type: 'POST',
         data: imagVote,
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function (data) {
             var result = eval(data.d);
         }
     });
 }

$('.VoteDownImage').live(click, function () {
    updateVote(this, 0);
});

$('.voteupImage').live(click, function () {
    updateVote(this, 1);
});

function manageVoting() {
    $("div.votemaincontainer").each(function () {
        // variable Declaration and intialization.
        var myRating = parseInt($(this).find('#[id$=hfMyVote]').val());
        var currentVote = parseInt($(this).find('#[id$=hfCurrentVote]').val());
    });

 }

$(function () {
    manageVoting();
});
```

One last piece of unwanted advice. **Don't make your code more complicated than it has to be**## Heading ##